# How to create the best Interactive R Language Online Learning Platform from the views of R community?

Tags: r, machine-learning

> R offers a breadth and depth in statistical computing beyond what is available in commercial 
>   closed source products. Yet R remains, primarily, a programming language for the highly 
>   skilled statistician, and out of the reach of many. --- The R Journal Vol. ½, December 2009

```
Note: Name changed from Interactive R Language Online Learning Platform: CloudStat School
```

As stated, R is the best tool and is the lingua franca of statistics. But many people, especially my students found difficulties to use R.

I wish to make an interactive R Learning Platform, called [CloudStat School](http://www.cloudstat.org/index.php?do=/blog/category/machine-learning-statistical-learning/).

The best way to learn R programming is doing while learning.

In CloudStat School, you will see a console box at your top left hand side, while the lesson notes at your top right. Bottom is the output box. Anything you “Run” in console box will be shown as a result in the output box.

So, while learning the notes, you can “run” the R examples immediately without open another windows, software or tabs. You can do it in a page.

I did make a simple working prototype:
[Lesson 1: Overview of R Language & CloudStat School](http://www.cloudstat.org/index.php?do=/kaichew/blog/lesson-1-overview-of-r-language-cloudstat-school/)

The prototype is simply integrating R Web that hosted in Pôle Bioinformatique Lyonnais in iframe.

If many of you think that this idea great, I would start making a better version.

This is my current simple idea, hope to get some feedback from you.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good luck with your project, that sounds like an excellent idea, in particular separating the syntax from the output. I agree that the best learning is through practice, and it is really hard to learn programming and statistics simultaneously. :)

Comment: Best of luck with your endeavor, but this isn't an appropriate "question" given the nature of the site. Perhaps promoting your site in chat would be a more appropriate venue? Or make the scope of the question much more refined (such as specific aspects of teaching), so it has an answerable question.

Comment: Welcome to our site, Kai Feng Chew!  Thank you for sharing your wonderful idea.  I believe many people would be glad to contribute ideas, but @Andy W is correct: you need to ask a specific question rather than just vaguely requesting "feedback."  Why don't you edit your question to specify what you want us to look at, what you would like to learn about your prototype, and what criteria you think should be used for evaluating it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm still new to here. My friend suggested me here to approach the R community, instead of making what I'm thinking is work. I had just changed the title into "How to create the best Interactive R Language Online Learning Platform from the views of R community?" So, I would like to collect some suggestions and examples to make a R learning platform that benefit not only my students but also everyone. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Michelle. It's still a beginning. Hope to receive some insightful suggestions from this community :)

Comment: Because you have changed the question to focus entirely on R programming, this question now appears to be most suitable for SO; it is off-topic at Stats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be much more resource intensive and require more effort to create, but check this out: I found [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/) to be a fun way to tinker with JavaScript. Unfortunately the site is (so far) only for a single language and a closed-source, venture-backed startup.

The main problem is that Rweb (as I am learning right now) does execute everything in batch, so this interpreted line-by-line approach used in CA probably cannot be done with it. If you were to create a similar app to CA for R, you'd have to open an R session for every user, hence the resource intensiveness disadvantage stated above. Hope this can be overcome, maybe someone will have an idea.

Hope you find this useful, at least as an inspiration for your endeavors. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: Code Academy is cool. The problem is we're just researchers with restricted resources and expertise. I afraid we can't do as good as Code Academy. I was thinking of [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/). 

Khan, a non-profit organization, is not as fancy as Code Academy, just with Youtube tutorial videos & quiz, but their achievement is amazing! 

Web-based R is one of my most research topics, such as RWeb, CrData, Opani, CloudNumbers, RStudio+AWS.... CloudStat is my current research project. Web R "line-by-line" is current obstacle. Only RStudio Server did that.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of pointers that might help: Eloquent **[Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html)** and **[CodingBat](http://codingbat.com/).**

Eloquent Javascript is an "*interactive Hyperbook*" where the students can edit and try out the examples right there in HTML as they are learning Javascript. Might be worth a look to get ideas for CloudStat.

In [CodingBat](http://codingbat.com/), Stanford professor Nick Parlante's has been doing (for Java and Python) exactly what you are attempting to do for R learners. Especially relevant is the [Authoring Page](http://codingbat.com/authoring.html#problem).

The success of your CloudStat School will be in getting crowdsourced contributions. To that end, my suggestion is for you to create 4-5 really good exercises with levels and hints, and then to focus on the 'meta' aspect of directing others to create the R exercises for you. Provide instructions for creating hints, tests, code, and tags. You could even consider assigning the task of 'creating new exercises' as a midterm/endterm projects to your R students for extra credit.

Hope that helps and good luck.

Comment: Crowd-learning is always the best way :) Instead of doing it alone, I should develop a platform. Your suggestion is brilliant. We should give it a try!

Comment: Recently, we had successfully developed a [ajax version of R web console](http://www.cloudstat.org/#rweb). By integrating this new feature, making a brand new [CloudStat School](http://www.cloudstat.org/index.php?do=/school/), an interactive R learning platform. Not really a big change, but more user-friendly :) Hope to receive your feedback~ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Commonly, there are two method of R Learning, one is step-by-step, like what CloudStat School is doing, as well as other R Language books and websites. This is good especially for those (newbie) learn R without specific purpose.

Another one is learn through problems. When you face specific problems, need specific functions, you are forced to learn it. Instead of "start from zero", the better way is learning through examples. This work even for experienced R users.

Since we want to make the best Interactive R Language Online Learning Platform, we need to add as many analysis examples/study cases here. If you need to get some ideas to make a statistical analysis with R, there is a place you will visit first. :)